# why display:none for "Select a option" in select in angular js?

Tags: angularjs

This is code for showing "select a option" in dropdown(select).

```
<select ng-model="form.type" required="required"
  ng-options="option.value as option.name for option in typeOptions" >
    <option style="display:none" value="">select a option</option>
</select>
```

can anybody explain me what is going on behind this code and what is use of display : none in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ng-options directive is like repeater and it will generate options and it will place them after the one with the disply:none which will be selected initially. Check the documentation for more info.

The idea behind the display:none option is to be hidden when the select is expanded so that you end up with valid selection.

Comment: what do you mean by "when the select is expanded"?? why its showing first time?

Comment: when you click on the select a list with options appears, and it is in "expanded" state

Comment: it is showing as selected initially, but it is not available to be selected from the drop down list. The purpose of the display:none is to be hidden for selection http://jsfiddle.net/0rrh9Lbb/

Answer (score 0):

With `style="display:none"` you wont be able to select 'select a option' from the dropdown list. Other than that your selection will be the value of option `option.value` but the text too choose from will be the name of option `as option.name` and each option comes from typeOptions.

I found [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vd73G/442/), try and remove the style="display:none" and see what happends, also try and remove the whole `<option style="display:none" value="">select a option</option>` line

Comment: why its showing first time while its style is "display :none"

Comment: you could just remove that whole line I think if u dont want it to show, you could say it's only there as a hint. The answer under mine describes it pretty good (selection is valid)

Answer (score 0):

The Angular select directive does this because of a wrinkle and how the select control works in the browser. If the select control initially has a value of "X", but there is no option element with value "X", the browser will automatically choose the first option from the list; without the user actually doing so. This is quite unhelpful, as it both generates a spurious change which Angular would then detect, and defeat the likely intention of the "required" setting, which is to require that the human (not the browser, automatically) make a choice.

In your example above, the value is the empty string "", but the same idea applies.

In the "bad old days" of programming the browser DOM by hand, this was also necessary for the same reasons.